# Instrumentation Test: onWebView().withElement() causing crash with 'Atom evaluation returned null'

Tags: android, kotlin, android-instrumentation, android-espresso-web

I am using Instrumentation tests to check that after a page has loaded in a WebView, certain behaviors work as expected. I currently have 3 tests which all work in this same way, i.e. wait for url to load > check the page title > do thing > check result.

The problem appears to be occur due to multiple functions calling the same `onWebView().withElement(findElement(Locator.CLASS_NAME, "my_title"))`. The test that completes first succeeds as expected, but subsequent tests fail with the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Atom evaluation returned null!
at androidx.test.espresso.web.sugar.Web$WebInteraction$ExceptionPropagator.<init>(Web.java:4)
at androidx.test.espresso.web.sugar.Web$WebInteraction.doEval(Web.java:17)
at androidx.test.espresso.web.sugar.Web$WebInteraction.withElement(Web.java:2)
```

I am calling `reset()`, which was originally missing so I assumed was the problem, however adding it has not solved the issue. See the code below:

```
    @get:Rule var activityScenarioRule = ActivityScenarioRule(BrowserActivity::class.java)

    @Test
    fun page_loads_and_can_navigate_via_footer() {
        onWebView()
            .withElement(findElement(Locator.CLASS_NAME, "my_title"))
            .withNoTimeout()
            .check(webMatches(getText(), containsString("title_1")))
            .withElement(findElement(Locator.ID, "footer_option_2"))
            .perform(webClick())
            .withElement(findElement(Locator.CLASS_NAME, "my_title"))
            .check(webMatches(getText(), containsString("title_2")))
            .reset()
    }

    @Test
    fun can_refresh_cache_in_debug_mode() {
        onWebView()
            .withElement(findElement(Locator.CLASS_NAME, "my_title"))
            .withNoTimeout()
            // DO TEST
            .reset()
    }

    @Test
    fun can_change_url_in_debug_mode() {
        onWebView()
            .withElement(findElement(Locator.CLASS_NAME, "my_title"))
            .withNoTimeout()
            // DO TEST
            .reset()
    }
```

Is there anything I am missing here? Or am I perhaps doing these tests wrong somehow?